# No output for some files in html report of eslint

Tags: vue.js, eslint

There are some problems when I use eslint to produce a html report.

In my `package.json` I have the following configuration:

```
"eslint-html": "eslint --format html ./src/* -o ./dist/eslint/index.html",
```

The output in the file `./dist/eslint/index.html` has a report for the following files:

```
src/App.vue
src/router/index.js
...
```

But no report for these files:

```
no src/components/pages/...
no src/components/*.vue
```

Why is there no output for any file in `src/components/`?

Comment: Double asterisk `./src/**`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

First you are providing `./src/*` as argument for `eslint`. This means: "all files in ./src". This does not include sub folders. To accept any number of sub folders provide `./src/**/*`

The second problem is that `eslint` does not know how to lint `.vue` files. For that you can install and configure an `eslint` plugin for vue files. Here is one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-vue

Comment: Thanks and when I provide ./src/**/* something goes to wrong.

Comment: Please define "something". Do you get an error message? Or do you get unexpected results?